# Stumped. How do i get data in vue from axios to display?

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have an axios call to an api that calls 22 objects in an array.

I want to save this from a computed, to data, then i want to loop through this in a select option with v-for.

Something like this:

```
<option v-for="item in items">{{item}}</option>

computed: {
    items(){
        return axios.post('API Call').then(response =>{ this.items = 
        response.data });
     }
}
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out where im going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usually the case, i resolved this by just hacking away at it. this is what i did to resolve the issue:

option:

```
    <option v-for="item in data" :value='item.id'>{{item.name}</option>
```

method:

```
    test_data: function(){
      var self = this;
      axios.post('API Call Here', {})
            .then(response => { 
                self.data = response.data;
                })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

And the data:

```
    data () {
      return {
        data:''
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `this.items` (as if it were a variable) inside `this.items` (which is a function: the computed property `items`) looks kinda wrong to me, but I've never seen that so I don't know the effect that has.

On the other hand, axios returns a promise, so if your computed is doing `return axios.whatever().then(etc)` you are going to get a promise out of the computed property, which is probably not what you want.

I think in this case you want to have `items` be a normal data property, and then do the axios call in a method or life cycle hook, or a watcher, and then when you do this:

```
data() { 
  return {
    items: [some default initial value here]
  }
},
created() {
  var self = this;
  axios.post('API Call').then(response => { 
    self.items = response.data
  });
}
```

`items` (now a data prop) will get assigned to `response.data` whenever the promise resolves successfully. (Notes: You probably know how your api formats your responses, but just in case, make sure `response.data` is actually what you want instead of, say, `response.body.data` or something. And make sure to add a catch or a rejection handler somewhere at some point too. EDIT: Whoops yeah, the other answer reminded me I forgot the "self")